# Tool frame massive in RViz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the robot view in RViz there is a blue sphere you can click to manually move the robot around, the tool frame. It is absolutely huge for me, about the size of my entire robot. Is there I can scale it down either in the urdf or RViz?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264136/tool-frame-massive-in-rviz/) by [cvancleef](https://answers.ros.org/users/30748/cvancleef/) on ROS Answers with karma: 24 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

LOL. In RViz, do you have a "Displays" panel open? (If not, click **Panels**-->**Displays**).

Then click on **Motion Planning** --> **Planning Request** --> adjust the **Interactice Marker Size**.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2017-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1